# Why does gtools::combinations and permutations not work with a vector containing the same elements?

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Say I have a vector `vec <- c("H", "H", "H", "H", "M", "M", "A", "A")`
How do I get all combinations / permutations if I e.g. draw 5 out of 8 with the expetced ouput.

```
> head(t, 6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
[2,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
[3,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "A" 
[4,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "A" 
[5,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "M" 
[6,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "A"
```

I tried `gtools::combinations()` but I always get the error that there are too few different elements (same is true for `gtools::permutations()` regardless if repeats are allowed or not.
So I did it in a laborious way

```
t <- gtools::combinations(8, 5, vec, repeats.allowed = F)
Error in gtools::combinations(8, 5, vec, repeats.allowed = F) : 
  too few different elements


t <- gtools::combinations(8, 5, letters[1:8], repeats.allowed = F)

for ( i in 1:8) {
  if ( i <=4 ) {
    t[t == letters[i]] <- "H" 
  } else if (i <= 6) {
    t[t == letters[i]] <- "M" 
  } else if (i <= 8) {
    t[t == letters[i]] <- "A" 
  }
}
```

I am looking for an easier solution from any package or base R and want to know, why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to include the duplicate results? For example, in your desired output, the first 2 rows are identical. Are you going to filter these later? If so, there are more direct and efficient algorithms for this.

Comment: For small vectors I would like to keep it but you are for big vector I would like to filter.  Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need combinations/permutations of a vector that contains repeats, or [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), many of the available functions in base `R` and other packages will produce unnecessary duplicate results that eventually need to be filtered out. For smaller problems, this is not an issue, however this approach quickly becomes impractical.

Currently, there are a couple of packages capable of handling these types of problems. They are `arrangements` and `RcppAlgos` (I am the author).

```
vec <- c("H", "H", "H", "H", "M", "M", "A", "A")
tbl_v <- table(vec)

tbl_v
vec
A H M 
2 4 2 

library(RcppAlgos)
comboGeneral(names(tbl_v), 5, freqs = tbl_v)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "H"  "H" 
[2,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
[3,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "M"  "M" 
[4,] "A"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H" 
[5,] "A"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
[6,] "A"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "M" 
[7,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
[8,] "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "M"

## For package arrangements we have:
## arrangements::combinations(names(tbl_v), 5, freq = tbl_v)
```

Similarly, for permutations, we have:

```
permuteGeneral(names(tbl_v), 5, freqs = tbl_v)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "H"  "H" 
  [2,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
  [3,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "M"  "H" 
  [4,] "A"  "A"  "H"  "M"  "M" 
     .   .    .    .    .    .
     .   .    .    .    .    .
     .   .    .    .    .    .
[137,] "M"  "M"  "H"  "A"  "A" 
[138,] "M"  "M"  "H"  "A"  "H" 
[139,] "M"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "A" 
[140,] "M"  "M"  "H"  "H"  "H" 

## For package arrangements we have:
## arrangements::permutations(names(tbl_v), 5, freq = tbl_v)
```

Both packages contain algorithms that generate each result without the need for filtering. This approach is much more efficient.

For example, what if we had `big_vec <- rep(vec, 8)` and we wanted all combinations of length 16. Using the filtering approach, one would need to generate all combinations of a vector of length 64 choose 16 and then filter them. That is `choose(64, 16) = 4.885269e+14` total combinations. That's going to be difficult.

With these two packages, this problem is a breeze.

```
big_vec <- rep(vec, 8)
tbl_big_v <- table(big_vec)

tbl_big_v
big_vec
 A  H  M 
16 32 16 

system.time(test_big <- comboGeneral(names(tbl_big_v), 16,
                                     freqs = tbl_big_v))
user  system elapsed 
   0       0       0 

dim(test_big)
[1] 153  16
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative

```
combn(vec,5)
```

which results in 56 combinations (`choose(8,5)`).

Comment: Didn't know that one. It's better than mine which relied on the package told about, as it is from the base package utils and the less dependencies, the best

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is indeed useful for the specific case I put as an example. For one other case only know `expand.grid()` but I am missing the other cases.

Answer (score 1):

`apply(gtools::combinations(8,5,repeats.allowed = FALSE),2,\(x) vec[x])`
does what you want.
I don't know why the package wants different values if applying it on a vector through. It's unclear within the documentation.